# Unnecessary scrollbar on my website for the slideshow animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar, slideshow

Part of my website has a full sized timed picture slideshow. The pictures animate and slide from right on top of the current picture. The issue that I am having is that the slideshow create a horizontal scrollbar at the bottom of the screen. When I scrolled the scroll bar I saw the next picture that was about to transition in. The user should not be able to see that. My code is below.

```
HTML
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" href= "Logo.png" type="img/SVG" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        .Header {
            position: fixed;
            z-index:1;
            width: 100%;
            height: 70px;
            background-color: black;
            text-align: right;
        }

        .socialmedia {
            position: fixed;
            right: 100px;
            top: 35px;
            transform: translate(0, -50%);
            display: flex;
            /* add this */
            align-items: center;
            /* add this */
        }

        .preorder button {
            background-color: white;
            border: 0;
            height: 35px;
            width: 110px;
            margin-left: 35px;
        }

        .footer {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            width: 100%;
            height: 90px;
            background-color: black;
        }

        .photoSection {
            position: relative;
            background-color: black;
        }

        .mySlides~.mySlides {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 100%;
            transition: 0.5s;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="Header" id="myHeader">
    <a class = "headerLogo">
        <a href="file:///C:/Noah's%20stuff/Home.html" ><h1 style="color:white; font-family: Verdana; font-style: italic; font-size: x-large;
        text-align: center;">Some Title</h1></a>
        <style>
            a{text-decoration: none}
        </style>

    </a>
    <div class="socialmedia">
        <a class = "Facebook">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><img src = "https://images.seeklogo.net/2016/09/facebook-icon-preview-1.png" width="50px" height="50px"></a>
        </a>
        <a class = "Instagram">
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/"><img src = "https://images.seeklogo.net/2016/06/Instagram-logo.png"  width="50px" height="50px"></a>
        </a>
        <a class = "Youtube">
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank"><img src = "https://images.seeklogo.net/2016/06/YouTube-icon.png" width="50px" height="50px"></a>
        </a>
        <a class = preorder>
            <button style = "background-color: white;">Pre-Order</button>

        </a>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="photoSection">
        <img class="mySlides" src="http://coolwildlife.com/wp-content/uploads/galleries/post-3004/Fox%20Picture%20003.jpg" style="width:100%; height:785px;">
        <img class="mySlides" src="http://ichef-1.bbci.co.uk/news/976/media/images/83351000/jpg/_83351965_explorer273lincolnshirewoldssouthpicturebynicholassilkstone.jpg" style="width:100%; height: 785px">
        <img class="mySlides" src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/2/1520/24330829813_944c817720_b.jpg" style="width:100%; height: 785px">
    </div>

<div class="section1" style = "background-color: black; color: white; padding-top: 150px;" >
    <a class = "header1" style="padding-left: 200px; display:inline-block; width:85.2%">
        <img src = "FoldingIcon.PNG">
        <h1 style = "font-family: Verdana;font-size: x-large; text-align: start;">Some Title</h1>
        <p style = "margin-bottom: 200px; font-family: Verdana; color: gray;">
        </p>
        <img src="Backpack.PNG">
        <h2 style = "font-family: Verdana; font-size: x-large; text-align:start">Some Title</h2>
        <p style = "margin-bottom: 300px"></p>
    </a>
    <p style = "color: gray; background-color: black; color: white; padding-left: 50px; display:inline-block; width:85.2%">
        ____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________</p>
</div>

<div class = "section2" style = "background-color: black; color: white; padding-bottom: 500px;">

</div>
<script>
    var myIndex = 0;
    carousel();

    function carousel() {
        var i;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

        }
        myIndex++;
        if (myIndex > x.length) {
            myIndex = 1
            x[myIndex - 1].style.right;
        }
        else {
            x[myIndex - 1].style.left = "0";
        }

        // you may want to add transition-delay , z-index, ... to tune sliding effect
        setTimeout(carousel, 3000); // Change image every 2 seconds
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to add overflow:hidden to your .photoSection css.

```
.photoSection {
        position: relative;
        background-color: black;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Comment: If the answer worked, you should accept the answer so person get credit for it. And if you have more questions, then you may open a new question, so other people searching through the internet with same issue may find your question and hopefully the answer.